# svchost.exe process takes 5GB of RAM, after some heavy browsing. What to do?

Tags: windows-7, memory, svchost

The Svchost.exe process takes 5GB of RAM after some heavy browsing with Chrome, even though I've closed the browser.  How can I prevent this behavior?

I have attached the associated services for that svchost process.

This is a Dell E5430 laptop, 12GB of RAM, Win7 x64. I have no special software installed/running that could cause such behavior, except for BitDefender Internet Security (this is on my first attempt trying it out on a PC).

[image: svchost.exe ram usage]

[image: svchost.exe associated services]

Comment: How long does the usage continue at those levels?  Try running tests without `emule.exe` running

Comment: It's steady, until I restart the PC. Sometimes it goes even higher.

Comment: If run some other demanding process besides a browser what happens?

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you: 1. Use different browsers, 2. [Start Windows in Safe Mode with Networking](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7), or 3. [Perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: It seems that it's actually from those 3 emule.exe instances. After closing them, the svchost.exe process went down from 5gb, to less than 200mb. Why? This never happened on my main PC, even though I had 3 instances of emule.exe running.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome and FF are notorious for leaking memory, taskman is ok but determining the insidious thread if that's what refusing to release the RAM is better determined with procexp.

I solved the problem with a "64-bit" Mozilla Nightly and that's caveated since the idea itself raises debate of what 64bit browsers are.

So far you also noticed Fonts is part of that svcprocess and Windows typically loads up its fonts at startup, a process you can quantify when logging start and shutdown issues using cperf or similar.

Do you have a lot of fonts installed on this box and are they mostly TTF's since I anecdotally notice Windows nearly scream in degradation after installing Adobe Creative Suite / Acrobat Distiller and open type fonts